# Codigniter backup library creating wrong insert query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am creating backup using codigniter library "dbutil" and i have fields in  my mysql database which having datatype bit when using below given code

```
 public function run_backup()
    {
        $filename="MembersPro_database_$this->curr_date.sql";
        $filepath="application/upload/DatabaseBackup/$filename";
        $dbfilepath="MembersPro/application/upload/DatabaseBackup/$filename";

        $prefs = array(
            'ignore'        => array(),                     // List of tables to omit from the backup
            'format'        => 'sql',                       // gzip, zip, txt
            'filename'      =>$filepath,                   // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
            'add_drop'      => TRUE,                        // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
            'add_insert'          => TRUE,
            "foreign_key_checks"  =>FALSE
           /* 'newline'       => "\n",*/
            // Newline character used in backup file
        );
        $backup="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `MembersManagmentSystem`; USE `MembersManagmentSystem` ";
        $backup .= $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
        if(!write_file($filepath, $backup))
        {
            echo "Error";die;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['sucessmsgbackup']="true";
        }
        $this->insert_into_datbase($filename,$dbfilepath);
        redirect("ViewDatabaseBackup");
    }
```

getting wrong output insert query

```
INSERT INTO `User` (`userId`, `userRoleId`,`userActive`, `userIsDelete`) VALUES ('20000046', '20001','1', '0');
```

in above given query "userActive" and "userIsDelete" fields having datatype "bit" and the query create by DbUtil library is treating it as string so i am getting warning error in mysql

```
"out of range column value"
```

Comment: Is this on a normal Linux server?

Comment: no it is on windows

Comment: Well that is sad. If on Linux you could have used mysqldump and in PHP is a one liner for complete backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read Here Why you should not use BIT columns in MySQL](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/)

<kbd>[**Issue reported Here in Github**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5260)</kbd>

Look into folder and modify core classes so that **it will not escape**, for example for mysqli driver

`system/database/drivers/mysqli`

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_utility.php#L159

and find file `mysqli_utility.php`

locate line

```
$is_int[$i] = in_array(strtolower($field->type),
                            array('tinyint', 'smallint', 'mediumint', 'int', 'bigint'), //, 'timestamp'),
                            TRUE);
```

Type numbers

```
numerics
-------------
BIT: 16
TINYINT: 1
BOOL: 1
SMALLINT: 2
MEDIUMINT: 9
INTEGER: 3
BIGINT: 8
SERIAL: 8
FLOAT: 4
DOUBLE: 5
DECIMAL: 246
NUMERIC: 246
FIXED: 246
```

and add your datatype to above array like below

```
$is_int[$i] = in_array($field->type,
                            array(16, 1, 2, 9, 3, 8),
                            TRUE);
```

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed you are welcome, thanks for reporting issue too

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed: above solution is just temporary for your datatype, bug has been fixed, please refer https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/9385cfed8e61c4568d5ec93c8ee8900f314a5a5a